# Getting System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. when creating a workflow

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

Creating a custom workflow.

I have an input which is an optionset.

I want to get the text value of this option set that is entered.

Convert it to decimal then add it to my output to populate another decimal field in Dyanimcs

```
var setvalue = hours.Get<OptionSetValue>(executionContext).ToString();

var hoursDecimal = Convert.ToDecimal(setvalue);
this.decimalval.Set(executionContext,hoursDecimal);
```

> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. is the error

Comment: What is the value of `setvalue` when you try to convert it to a decimal?

Comment: 7.5 is the value

Comment: Let me just add the list of option set values is a list of decimals so the options are 2.5,1.0 and so on

Comment: @jonathan Use `Decimal.TryParse` method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

In your case, using the `Decimal.TryParse` method with yield the correct result that you want. In your code:

```
var setvalue = hours.Get<OptionSetValue>(executionContext).ToString();
decimal parsedsetvalue;

if(decimal.TryParse(setvalue,out parsedsetvalue))
{ 
  // success - can use parsedsetvalue
  this.decimalval.Set(executionContext,parsedsetvalue);
}
else
{
  //error in coverting parsedsetvalue to decimal
  return "Error, could not convert setvalue to decimal";
}
```